# SQL - Can I create a continuous Count which resets when a value hits 0

Tags: sql, count

got this data set and i need sql code to return "MonthCount".

It returns a count against the DateYYYYMM and Account Number where Payment is not 0.
When Payment goes to 0 the count should be 0. When payment starts again the count starts again from 1.

[image]

Big thanks in advance

I've tried various LAG/Case statements but I can only get a return of a count when Payment isn't 0.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please take the tour like you were asked to when you signed up and visit the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for good advice about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation to produce groups of rows. Then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate the count you want. For example:

```
select row_number() over(partition by g order by dateyyyymm) - 1 as monthcount
from (
  select sum(case when payment = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
         over(order by dateyyyymm) as g 
  from t
) x
```